# A function that is integrable over the closure of an open set but not over the set itself

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to find a bounded function $f$ and an open set $A$ such that $f$ is integrable over $\overline{A}$ but not over $A$.

Is there such a function and set?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean Riemann integrable. There is no such function and set.

A bounded function $f$ is Riemann integrable *iff* the set of points at which it's not continuous has Lebesgue measure $0$. By hypothesis, then, the set of points at which $f|\overline{A}$ is discontinuous has measure $0$. This set contains the points of discontinuity of $f|A$, so that set has measure $0$ too. Of course, $f|A$ is also bounded. So $f|A$ is Riemann integrable.

Comment: What about if $\int_{\overline{A}}f$ exists but $\int_Af$ does not?

Comment: But, but, ... $f$ integrable on $X$ means $\int_X f$ exists.

Comment: Well it's a problem on Analysis on Manifolds and it does seem to ask for an example... Could it be that $\int_\overline{A}f$ exists but $f$ is not integrable over $\overline{A}$?

Comment: Well, if that could be the case then I'm missing something, though I don't think so. Sorry! (Again, "the integral of $f$ on $X$ exists" $\iff$ "$f$ is integrable on $X$".)