# Example on Existence of integral of function over a bounded open set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Let A be a bounded open set in Rn. Letf :Rn →R be bounded and continuous function. Show an instance where $\int_\overline A f $exists but $\int_ A f $ does not.

If it is the closure, then I do not think this is possible. This is also stated by another answer: [A function that is integrable over the closure of an open set but not over the set itself](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559267/a-function-that-is-integrable-over-the-closure-of-an-open-set-but-not-over-the-s). So am i missing something?

Comment: I think the bar indicates closure, not the complement.

Comment: got it, can you give me a hint or example on the closure in this case? it doesn't make sense to me how the closure can be integrable but the open set contained is not